# How to fill default -(hyphen) to empty cells

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I need to default empty cells of my primeng datatable to '-'. Can anyone share how.

Suppose that my data is:

```
[
{
 'column': null
},
{
 'column': {
  'name': 'A'
 }
},
{
 'column': {
  'name': 'B'
 }
},
{
 'column': null
}
]
```

My primeng column configuration looks like:

```
{  
 field: 'column.name',
 header: 'Name',
 sortable: true
}
```

But, the below does not work as *"column"*
 is not always supposed to have the property *"name"*. And the below turns all my fields of this column to '-', irrespective of if it has "name" or not.

```
 <p-column [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header" [sortable]="col.sortable">
     <template let-col let-data="rowData" pTemplate="body">
         {{data[col.field] ? data[col.field] : "-"}}
     </template>
 </p-column>
```

Please help!

Comment: Would be great if you upvote while you come across this question, so that I could get an answer at earliest. :(

Answer (score 0):

I used [Angular2 custom pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) for this.

How to:

1. You'll need to create a custom pipe [read more about how here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html):

```js
import {
  Pipe,
  PipeTransform
} from '@angular/core';
/*
 * If piped value is falsy, default to given default value or - (hyphen)
 * Takes an defaultValue argument that defaults to - (hyphen).
 * Usage:
 *   value | defaultTo:'N/A'
 * Example:
 *   {{ orders.attributes?.first_name | defaultTo}}
 *   formats to: -
 *
 * Written by Henrik Peinar 06/04/2017
 */
@Pipe({
  name: 'defaultTo'
})
export class DefaultToPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(value: string, defaultValue?: string): string {
    return (value) ? value : (defaultValue !== undefined ? defaultValue : '-');
  }
}
```

2. Add your pipe to your app's declarations so it is available for use:

```js
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
// ... other imports ...
import { DefaultToPipe } from './default-to.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, HttpModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, DefaultToPipe ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

3. Use your newly created pipe in any of your templates like so:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let order of orderList">
      <td>{{order.order_number}}</td>
      <td>{{order.phone | defaultTo:'No phone'}}</td>
      <td>{{order.shipping_address?.first_name | defaultTo}}</td>
      <td>{{order.shipping_address?.last_name  | defaultTo}}</td>
</tr>
```

*I didn't create fully working snippet because I didn't find Angular2 as a possible dependency in the snippet provider.*

Comment: Thanks @Henrik for your effort, but my actual problem is with primeng-datatables not displaying those columns that have proper data. It formats every cell, irrespective of data being present.

Comment: I see. The question title is far too general and as I landed here with my search, I thought I'd post my answer if someone else with the same search comes along. Sorry it didn't help you much.